Issue with calling API using Python Requests on Ubuntu Server
I am working on a Python script that scrapes announcements from the NSE website using requests and proxies. The script works perfectly fine on my local machine (Windows), but when I run it on an Ubuntu server, the request fails while using proxies for the NSE endpoint.
Problem Description
The issue occurs while sending a GET request to the NSE URL during the session setup. Here’s the problematic line:
response = session_nse.get(NSE_URL, headers=NSE_HEADERS, proxies=proxy_config, timeout=15)

The proxy_config is set up like this:
proxy = random.choice(PROXIES)
proxy_config = {
    "http": f"http://{proxy}",
    "https": f"http://{proxy}"
}

Note: I tried with and without using proxies.
Observed Behavior
Local Machine (Windows): Works without any issues. The response is received successfully.

Ubuntu Server:
The request either times out or throws an exception like ProxyError or Max retries exceeded with URL.
Environment:
Local Machine: Windows 10, Python 3.12.4

Server: Ubuntu 22.04, Python 3.10.12
Questions

Why might the proxies fail on the Ubuntu server but work locally on Windows?

Are there any configurations or system settings I should check on the Ubuntu server?


@Hannu Excuse me but you might have posted the wrong link

Now, I wonder if this isn't a similar issue as shown here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/79236983/3720510  (correct link)
